# What can I expirement with BitcoinCore on my own?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, bitcoin-cli, regtest

I have a simple faculty assignment where I have to do some experiments with transactions or experiment with the Bitcoin protocol or maybe with wallet code. Work on that assignment shouldn't last more than one day, however I cannot imagine anything I can actually do on my own. Every change in code seems too complex for me or pointless. All my changes will be tested on `testnet` or `regtest` and never published of course. Can someone help me with this with some sort of direction, link to some other experiments or maybe with a simple idea or pseudo code example? 
Thank  you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lot of things you can learn and try from below link including designing complex bitcoin scripts:

https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line