# About Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, script

I have just downloaded the Bitcoin Core from https://bitcoin.org/en/download

I would like to ask the following since I have read the following article:

1. https://blockgeeks.com/guides/best-bitcoin-script-guide/
2. https://blockgeeks.com/guides/bitcoin-script-guide-part-2/

Is that downloaded Bitcoin Core features the same as the above 2 articles? Am I able to create my deposit and send transactions to include the fee and select peers?

Appreciate your kind guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the GUI (the visual window interface), you should be able to do all of those things. If you only installed the command line version, type `bitcoin-cli help` into your terminal to see a list of commands. `bitcoin-cli help <command>` will give you info on what each command does.

Comment: Thanks for the command line version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can read and try things mentioned in those articles using Bitcoin Core

Also refer to this link: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/98433/103136